# How to update the expected result in Test Execution Result (Test-Logs) Under a Specific Test-Run on QTest by Rest API

Tags: qtest

I'm using the following REST API to update the expected result in Test Execution Result (Test-Logs) Under a Specific Test-Run on QTest

Sample API:
**{{QTestURL}}/api/v3/projects/{{QtestProjectID}}/test-runs/{{testRunID}}/test-logs/{{testLogID}}**

Method Type: **PUT**

Body Json Payload :

```
{
    "id": 240088935,
    "test_case_version_id": 68905981,
    "exe_start_date": "2023-02-03T15:09:14+00:00",
    "exe_end_date": "2023-02-03T15:11:44+00:00",
    "user_id": 388566,
    "planned_exe_time": 0,
    "actual_exe_time": 0,
    "automation": false,
    "properties": [
        {
            "field_id": 11364197,
            "field_name": "Tester",
            "field_value": "388566",
            "field_value_name": "Kings ton"
        },
        {
            "field_id": 11364187,
            "field_name": "Execution Type",
            "field_value": "501",
            "field_value_name": "Functional"
        },
        {
            "field_id": 11364188,
            "field_name": "Planned Start Date",
            "field_value": "2023-04-20T00:00:00+00:00"
        },
        {
            "field_id": 11364190,
            "field_name": "Planned End Date",
            "field_value": "2023-05-10T00:00:00+00:00"
        },
        {
            "field_id": 11364191,
            "field_name": "Test Case Version",
            "field_value": "3.0"
        },
        {
            "field_id": 11364192,
            "field_name": "Target Release/Build",
            "field_value": "",
            "field_value_name": ""
        },
        {
            "field_id": 11364196,
            "field_name": "Status",
            "field_value": "602",
            "field_value_name": "Failed"
        }
    ],
    "status": {
        "links": [],
        "id": 601,
        "name": "Passed"
    },
    "result_number": 1,
    "test_step_logs": [
        {
            "test_step_id": 476945980,
            "test_step_log_id": 832043439,
            "user_id": 388566,
            "status": {
                "links": [],
                "id": 601,
                "name": "Passed"
            },
            "description": "<p>Step 1</p>",
            "expected_result": "Step 1 Expected Result",
            "actualResult": "Step 1 Actual Result",
            "order": 1,
            "group": 0,
            "defects": []
        },
        {
            "test_step_id": 476945981,
            "test_step_log_id": 832043440,
            "user_id": 388566,
            "status": {
                "links": [],
                "id": 602,
                "name": "Failed"
            },
            "description": "<p>Step 2</p>",
            "expected_result": "Step 2 Expected Result",
            "order": 2,
            "group": 0,
            "defects": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I changed the value in expected and actual results and hit the API call.
Response Received: **200 OK**, but the expected result value doesn't change but the actual result value is updated on qTest.

Can anyone help me with this?